# How to START Cassandra node having table that did not have any partition key column in the schema tables

Tags: cassandra, nosql, bigdata

i have come across serious issue on Cassandra having single node.
I ran drop materialize view/tables all together (almost 10-15 drop statements with creation of table/views queries as well) from DataStax DevCenter but it threw Operation failed error and cassandra went down after it.

When i started cassandra it failed. and cassandra logs showing:

```
Exception (java.lang.AssertionError) encountered during startup: Table keyspace.table did not have any partition key columns in the schema tables
ERROR 08:19:00 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AssertionError: Table keyspace.table did not have any partition key columns in the schema tables
at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:950) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:925) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:888) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:865) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:853) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:136) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:126) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:260) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
```

Now how can i fix this case?

Comment: Can you put the query here?

Comment: Queries do contain partitionkkey defined. it crashed in DEVCenter. where data is above 100K in respective tables.

Comment: I tired SSTtable scrub,utilities but all failed and showed above exception. But some how i was able resolve issue by copying system_schema folder from another machine to corrupted machine.

Comment: Okay. it seems issue was due to sstable corruption.